# How to maintain the state of ListView

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview

I am currently using a listview in asp.net. When I click search it shows a number of columns. When I go to another page, then go back to the original page, is there a way to keep the state of the original ListView so that the user does not have to search again?

My initial thoughts were to use AJAX tools but I am not sure how I would handle that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do it via the back end code and would depend on how you've setup the datasource of the view. If you are filling the datasource of the view on the back end; as in with a dataset; then you can cache the dataset in the session.

The next time the page is visited before you fill the dataset check to see if the session object exists, and if it does, get the dataset from the session and assign it back to the listview.

A more memory efficient way to do it is by storing the search parameters in the session, instead of the entire dataset. Onpageload if the search parameters are in session then extract them and use them to run the search automatically. You can also then assign the values back to  the filter fields on the form, if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

I'd save the parameters of the search in a 'UsersSearchtbl' in my database and get the parameters back each time the search page is hit for the first time. That way, when the user leaves the site and comes back, you can display the last search (if that is useful).